In Kafka, how to manage permission of each consumer with Spring Boot?
I started my kafka using docker-compose
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

According to this Structure. There are several consumers and several topic. However, how can I do if i would like to restrict a consumer to only listen and read message from specific topic using Spring Boot? Is there any config I can set?

Set permission to each consumer?

Can you share some experience, please, how would you do that without Spring Boot? The point is that these fine-grained permissions on Kafka topics and their consumers are out of Spring scope. This is something what Apache Kafka client should provide. Perhaps via specific consumer config.
